# Send data between apps in Android

Tags: android, service, ipc, aidl

For communication between different android apps, we have AIDL as an option for 2 way communication. Now, I am able to send data from client app to server app(which contains the AIDL service) successfully. But, I got stuck on sending data from server to client. Any help will be appreciable.

For reference:- https://github.com/romulo-soares/aidl-comunication-android

I took reference from this demo and modified it.

App1 which was named as Server:-

AIDLPrincipalService class

```
public class AIDLPrincipalService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "AIDLPrincipalService";
private AIDLPrincipalImpl aidlPrincipal;

public AIDLPrincipalService(){
    aidlPrincipal = new AIDLPrincipalImpl();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return aidlPrincipal;
}

public static class AIDLPrincipalImpl extends AIDLPrincipal.Stub {

    @Override
    public double somar(double a, double b) throws RemoteException {
        Log.e(TAG, "somar: " + a + "<>" + b);
//            String msg = value + "sent from server again";
        return (a + b);
    }

    @Override
    public double subtrair(double a, double b) throws RemoteException {
        Log.e(TAG, "subtrair: " + a + "<>" + b);
        return (a - b);
    }

    @Override
    public double multiplicar(double a, double b) throws RemoteException {
        Log.e(TAG, "multiplicar: " + a + "<>" + b);
        return (a * b);
    }

    @Override
    public double dividir(double a, double b) throws RemoteException {
        Log.e(TAG, "dividir: " + a + "<>" + b);
        return (a / b);
    }

    @Override
    public String message(String message) throws RemoteException {
        Log.e("AIDlPrincipalService", "::>>>message: " + message);
        String msg = message + " , sent from server";
        return msg;
     }
  }

}
```

AIDL file

```
interface AIDLPrincipal {

   double somar(double a, double b);
   double subtrair(double a, double b);
   double multiplicar(double a, double b);
   double dividir(double a, double b);
   String message(String message);

}
```

Note:- The above file is used for both apps.

MainActivity of App1:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnMsgToClient;
TextView textView;
private AIDLPrincipalService.AIDLPrincipalImpl aidlPrincipal;
private ServiceConnection serviceConnection;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    btnMsgToClient = findViewById(R.id.btnMsgToClient);

    btnMsgToClient.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String msg = textView.getText().toString();
            try {
                executeSendMsgFromServerToClient(msg);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void executeSendMsgFromServerToClient(String msg) throws RemoteException {
    aidlPrincipal = new AIDLPrincipalService.AIDLPrincipalImpl();
    String newdata = aidlPrincipal.message(msg);
    Log.e("MAinActivity", "::>>" + newdata);
}
```

In Manifest file, I have just defined the service which is mentioned above.

Now, the second app(Client app) is defined as below:-
MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AIDLPrincipal aidlPrincipal;
private ServiceConnection serviceConnection;
private EditText etValorA, etValorB, edtMessage, edtResult;
private TextView tvResultado;
private AIDLPrincipalImpl aidlPrincipalImpl;

public void onClickSoma(View view) throws RemoteException {
    tvResultado.setText(String.valueOf(executeOperations(etValorA, etValorB, edtMessage, OperationEnum.SOMAR)));
}

public void onClickSubtrai(View view) throws RemoteException {
    tvResultado.setText(String.valueOf(executeOperations(etValorA, etValorB, edtMessage, OperationEnum.SUBTRAIR)));
}

public void onClickMultiplica(View view) throws RemoteException {
    tvResultado.setText(String.valueOf(executeOperations(etValorA, etValorB, edtMessage, OperationEnum.MULTIPLICAR)));
}

public void onClickDivide(View view) throws RemoteException {
    tvResultado.setText(String.valueOf(executeOperations(etValorA, etValorB, edtMessage, OperationEnum.DIVIDIR)));
}

public void onClickMsg(View view) throws RemoteException {
    edtResult.setText(String.valueOf(executeMessageOperations(edtMessage, OperationEnum.MESSAGE)));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etValorA = findViewById(R.id.etValorA);
    etValorB = findViewById(R.id.etValorB);
    edtMessage = findViewById(R.id.edtMessage);
    edtResult = findViewById(R.id.edtResult);
    tvResultado = findViewById(R.id.tvResultado);

    //Service Connection for comunication App Server
    serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            Log.i("TAG", "onServiceConnected");
            aidlPrincipal = AIDLPrincipal.Stub.asInterface(service);
            aidlPrincipalImpl = new AIDLPrincipalImpl();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            Log.i("TAG", "onServiceDisconnected");
            aidlPrincipal = null;
        }
    };

    //Intent initialize service
    Intent intent = new Intent("br.edu.ifpb.aidlservercalculator.CALCULATE");
    intent.setPackage("br.edu.ifpb.aidlservercalculator");
    bindService(intent, serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

}

private double executeOperations(EditText etValueA, EditText etValueB, EditText edtMessage, OperationEnum operacao) throws RemoteException {

    double a = Double.parseDouble(etValorA.getText().toString());
    double b = Double.parseDouble(etValorB.getText().toString());
    String msg = edtMessage.getText().toString();

    if (operacao.equals(OperationEnum.SOMAR)){
        return aidlPrincipal.somar(a,b);
    } else if (operacao.equals(OperationEnum.SUBTRAIR)){
        return aidlPrincipal.subtrair(a,b);
    } else if (operacao.equals(OperationEnum.MULTIPLICAR)){
        return aidlPrincipal.multiplicar(a,b);
    } else {
        return aidlPrincipal.dividir(a,b);
    }
}

private String executeMessageOperations(EditText edtMessage, OperationEnum message) throws RemoteException {
    String msg = edtMessage.getText().toString();
    return aidlPrincipal.message(msg);
}

public class AIDLPrincipalImpl extends AIDLPrincipal.Stub {

    @Override
    public double somar(double a, double b) throws RemoteException {
        Log.e("TAG", "somar: " + a + "<>" + b);
        return (a + b);
    }

    @Override
    public double subtrair(double a, double b) throws RemoteException {
        Log.e("TAG", "subtrair: " + a + "<>" + b);
        return (a - b);
    }

    @Override
    public double multiplicar(double a, double b) throws RemoteException 
{
        Log.e("TAG", "multiplicar: " + a + "<>" + b);
        return (a * b);
    }

    @Override
    public double dividir(double a, double b) throws RemoteException {
        Log.e("TAG", "dividir: " + a + "<>" + b);
        return (a / b);
    }

    @Override
    public String message(String message) throws RemoteException {
        Log.e("AIDlPrincipalService", "::>>>message: " + message);
        edtResult.setText(message);
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

The OperationEnum file mentioned in the 2nd app code is as below:-

```
public enum OperationEnum {

SOMAR, SUBTRAIR, MULTIPLICAR, DIVIDIR, MESSAGE

}
```

Now, the MainActivity of client app is defined in Manifest file.
Here I can able to send data from 2nd app (client app) to 1st app (server app) successfully. But not able to send data from 1st app (Server app) to 2nd app(client app).

Comment: We do not know what you tried. I show some options in the "Remote Services and the Binding Pattern" of [this free older book](https://commonsware.com/Android/).

Comment: I have attached a reference project link which I have tried. @CommonsWare

Comment: Yes, but we do not know how you used that reference project and we do not know what "I got stuck" means. You may have better luck getting help here if you explain, with your own [mcve], what "I got stuck" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare Please check for the code of both apps. It will define the both apps and the communication process.

Comment: What does "But not able to send data from 1st app (Server app) to 2nd app(client app)" mean? Other than return values from your AIDL-defined functions, you have no code to send data from the service back to the client.

Comment: Please check the MainActivity of 1st app as I have tried to call the method of service but I am sure it is not correct. @CommonsWare

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247123/discussion-between-nikhil-and-commonsware).

Answer (score 0):

For Android 11 (API level 30) you may also need to specify a query with the package of the app you want to interact with:

```
<manifest package="com.example.app">
  <queries>
    <!-- Specific apps you interact with, eg: -->
    <package android:name="com.example.service" />
  </queries>
  ...
</manifest>
```