# What does two-way communication means in AIDL & messenger in IPC android

Tags: android, ipc, aidl

Currently I am integrating inter process communication between apps. So during search of it I found 3 methods:-

1.) AIDL (two-way communication concurrent)

2.) Messenger (two-way communication)

3.) Broadcast receiver (one way)

Now looking for AIDL & Messenger, I understand the term and functionality of concurrent. But both of the is working as starts a service form server app and connect the client app to server app which works perfect during client to server data transfer. But I don't know how to send data from server to client. There is nothing found on internet as every demo/example shows only client to server communication using these methods. How can I transfer data from server to client? Or if it is not possible then how is this two-way communication?

Comment: "But I don't know how to send data from server to client" -- [as I mentioned yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73278114/send-data-between-apps-in-android#comment129413033_73278114), I show some options in the "Remote Services and the Binding Pattern" of [this free older book](https://commonsware.com/Android/). "There is nothing found on internet as every demo/example shows only client to server communication using these methods" -- the book that I linked to, and [that chapter's associated samples](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Binding) are on the Internet.

Comment: If your question is "how do I send data from the service to the client without first communicating from the client to the service", you could use a `BroadcastReceiver`, as noted in your list. The `BroadcastReceiver` can pass a `Messenger` (or *maybe* and AIDL-based `Binder`) as an extra. Or, you could simply invert your communications, and have services and clients in both apps, and use whatever form of IPC you want.